# Probability of correlated random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables defined as $W=\frac{X}{Y+1}$ and  $Z=\frac{Y}{X+1}$. I want to find $$\Pr\left(W<a,Z<a\right)$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. exponential as $e^{-t}$
Since $W$ and $Z$ are functions of same $X$ and $Y$, I am not sure how to separate them  as we use in independent variables.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>0$. Then
$$\Pr\left(W<a,Z<a\right) = \Pr\left(\frac{X}{a}-1<Y<aX+a\right)$$
Since $\frac{X}{a}-1<0$ if $X<a$, the probability can be merged into two probabililties
$$\Pr\left(W<a,Z<a\right) =\Pr\left(0<Y<aX+a, X<a\right)+\Pr\left(\frac{X}{a}-1<Y<aX+a, X>a\right)$$
The first one equals to
$$
\Pr\left(0<Y<aX+a, X<a\right) = \int_0^a \int_0^{ax+a} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dy\,dx.
$$
Similar for the second one.

ADDED:

To write the second probability as integral, one need to check whether $\frac{X}{a}-1$ is less than $aX+a$. For $a>1$ it is always true, but for $a<1$ it is true when $X<\frac{a}{1-a}$ only. So, for $a<1$ the second probability will be $$\int_a^{a/(1-a)}\int_{x/a-1}^{ax+a} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dy\,dx,$$
and for $a\geq 1$ the second probability will be 
$$\int_a^{\infty}\int_{x/a-1}^{ax+a} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dy\,dx.$$

Comment: When I simplify it, I got $1-2e^{-a}/(1+a)$ which gives -1 when $a$ goes to 0. Seems I am doing a mistake.

Comment: To write the second probability as integral, one need to check whether $\frac{X}{a}-1$ is less then $aX+a$. For $a>1$ it is always true, but for $a<1$ it is true when $X<\frac{a}{1-a}$ only. So, for $a<1$ the second probability will be $$\int_a^{a/(1-a)}\int_{x/a-1}^{ax+a} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: I added this explanation to the answer.